# Increase tab size in Qt works on linux but not on mac

Tags: c++, css, linux, macos, qt

I am a newbie to Qt5. After finding many vain answers to my problem like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35255032/why-does-qt-designer-re-size-or-not-allow-me-to-shrink-or-expand-widgets-or-butt), I ended up here. As shown in the Image, My tab resizes on writing the following CSS perfectly well in Linux. But, it shows no effect on my mac i.e. the size doesn't change.

CSS:

```
 ui->tabWidget->setStyleSheet("QTabBar::tab { height: 100px; width: 110px; }");
```

What can be the possible problem? Many thanks for help.    [image]

Comment: Tabcontrol behaves differently on Mac, please have a look here for advices https://forum.qt.io/topic/67818/text-in-a-qtabbar-qtabwidget-on-macos-and-linux (see min-width, though the whole thread may be useful)